# Manual slicing of a list using their indices, Python

Tags: python, list, numpy, list-comprehension, slice

**Minimal example**

I have a list `a = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120,130,140,150,....,]`

I want to get a new list `new_list = [40,50,60,100,110,120,...]`, i.e. append fourth, fifth and sixth value, skip next three, append next three and so on.

My idea is to create a list called `index`:

`index = [3,4,5,9,10,11,...]
new_list = [a[i] for i in index] # This should give me what I want`

but how do I create the list `index` ? I know `np.arange` has the step option, but that is only for spacing between values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way -

```
[a[i] for i in range(len(a)) if i%6>=3]
```

Sample run -

```
In [49]: a = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120,130,140,150]

In [50]: [a[i] for i in range(len(a)) if i%6>=3]
Out[50]: [40, 50, 60, 100, 110, 120]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an improved and faster version using Python built-in function `enumerate` building up on [Divakar's nice logic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52773057/2956066).

```
In [4]: lst = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 130, 140, 150]
In [6]: [item for idx, item in enumerate(lst) if idx%6 >= 3]
Out[6]: [40, 50, 60, 100, 110, 120]
```

---

**why is this version better & preferable?**

```
In [10]: lst = range(10, 100000, 10)       

In [11]: %timeit [lst[idx] for idx in range(len(lst)) if idx % 6 >= 3]
1.1 ms ± 22.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [12]: %timeit [item for idx, item in enumerate(lst) if idx % 6 >= 3]
788 µs ± 8.67 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

That's more than 300 microseconds gain! Furthermore, `enumerate()` is more straightforward and intuitive (c.f. [loop like a native](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/iter.html))

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the index elements of continuous 3 increment and repeat of 3 elements

```
a = np.asarray([10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120,130,140,150])
b = np.tile(np.arange(1,4),int(len(a)/6)+1) + np.repeat(np.arange(3,int(len(a)/2)+3,3),3)
a.take(b)
```

Out:

```
array([ 50,  60,  70,  80,  90, 100, 110, 120, 130])
```

Explanation

```
np.tile(np.arange(1,4),int(len(a)/6)+1)
#array([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3])

np.repeat(np.arange(3,int(len(a)/2)+3,3),3)
#array([3, 3, 3, 6, 6, 6, 9, 9, 9])
```